# How to save and test CNN model on test set after training

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, cnn

My CNN model is trained on the training set and validated on the validation set, now I want to test it on test set, here is my code:

```
x_img = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='x_img')
y_label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='y_label')
reshape = tf.reshape(x_img, shape=[-1, img_x, img_y, img_z, 1], name='reshape')

def CNN_Model(input):    
    conv1 = conv_layer(reshape, num_channels, n_f_conv1, name="conv1")    
    max_pool1 = maxpool_layer(conv1, name="max_pool1")    
    conv2 = conv_layer(max_pool1, n_f_conv1, n_f_conv2, name="conv2")  
    max_pool2 = maxpool_layer(conv2, name="max_pool2")
    shape = 4*4*4*64
    flattened = tf.reshape(max_pool2,shape=[-1, shape], name='flattened')
    fc = fc_layer(flattened, shape, n_node_fc, name="fc")
    dropout1 = dropout(fc, keep_rate, name="dropout1")
    output_layer = output(dropout1, n_node_fc, num_classes, name="output_layer") 
    return output_layer

def train_CNN(input):
    train_predict = CNN_Model(x_img)
    with tf.variable_scope("cross_entropy", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        lose = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=train_predict, labels=y_label, name='cross_entropy')
        cost = tf.reduce_mean(lose, name='reduce_mean_cost')
        tf.summary.scalar("cost", cost)

    with tf.variable_scope("optimization", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate, name='AdamOptimizer').minimize(cost)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    print("Starting session...")
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        all_time = 0
        batch_size = 120
        batch = 0
        print("Starting training...")
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            train_batch = train_data[batch:batch_size]
            batch += batch_size
            batch_size += batch_size
            start_time = time.time()
            ep_loss = 0
            for data in train_batch:
                X = data[0]
                Y = data[1]
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x_img: X, y_label: Y})
                ep_loss += c
            end_time = time.time()
            all_time += int(end_time-start_time)
            print('Epoch', epoch+1, 'completed out of',num_epochs,'loss:',ep_loss, 
                  'time usage: '+str(int(end_time-start_time))+' seconds')


        correct_predict = tf.equal(tf.argmax(train_predict, 1), tf.argmax(y_label, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predict, tf.float32), name='reduce_mean_acc')
        print("Validation accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x_img:[i[0] for i in validate_data], 
                                               y_label:[i[1] for i in validate_data]}))
        print("Test accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x_img:[i[0] for i in test_data], 
                                               y_label:[i[1] for i in test_data]}))
```

I have a test dataset stored as `test_data` like `train_data` in the code above, tried to do it in more than one way, but I did not succeed, can anyone share a testing code with me, ofcourse based on my code?

Comment: This code just shows the optimisation operations you have done. Do have any place holder in your `CNN_Model`?

Comment: @Media, added some other parts of the code, I can add more if needed.

Comment: What you need to do is feeding your test data in the feed_dict of the run function.

Comment: can you do it by code? as I said I tried more than one time without success. anything you need I can provide it.

Comment: Let me know if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly where you have the problem but according to comments, take a look at the following line.

```
_, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x_img: X, y_label: Y})
```

`feed_dict` is used for passing data to your network. As you can see, `X` is the training data. You can replace it with the test data. You should also change the `y_labels` to the labels of the test data.

Comment: see the code, you mean something like this?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Consider this kind of coding of NNs as a kind of machine that you have tuned its bolts and nuts and you just input something, placeholders, and you get your results.

Comment: ok but I have a problem with that, with only 600 sample of data (360 for training, 120 for each of validation and testing) I get 95% of accuracy for both validation and test, I think this is not real accuracy with this amount of data?

Comment: Yes, your set is small for training deep models.

Comment: I know it's very small, but why I get 95% of accuracy? have you any idea?

Comment: What is your train accuracy?

Comment: train data is used only for training not to check for accuracy. can I do it the same way as validation and test accuracy? or adding it inside train_data loop?

Comment: I guess you have not understood the concept of placeholders yet, try to search for that. Yes, you can and you have to, in order to investigate whether you've overfit the data or not.

Comment: Take a look at [here](https://learningtensorflow.com/lesson4/).

Comment: I get 0.5 train accuracy?

Comment: I don't know! Are you asking me? :) If your sentence is declarative means you are not overfitting your training data. You should train it more.